# JSON_EXTRACT not working with booleans in BigQuery

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I have a JSON from Firebase that looks like this:

```
    {
    'name' : 'starbyone',
    'foo': {'id': 123},
    'somebit': True,
    'bar': {'_a': 123, '_b': 456}
    }
```

I'm using BigQuery and am tyring to extract 'foo' by using `JSON_EXTRACT`function:

```
SELECT 
    JSON_EXTRACT(json, "$.name") as Works,
    JSON_EXTRACT(json, "$.foo") as AlsoWorks,
    JSON_EXTRACT(json, "$.bar") as DoesNotWork
FROM schema.table
```

The issue however, is that the third column (aliased DoesNotWork) simply returns NULL, while 'Foo' will return a string "{'id': 123}"

I've also tried JSON_VALUE , to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

This simple snippet doesn't seem to work for me either:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT("{'category': 1, 'comments': [], 'free': False,'price': 55","$.price") AS Result
```

Comment: you have missing comma before the `foo` - rather than this  - works for me  - output is [
  {
    "Works": "\"starbyone\"",
    "AlsoWorks": "{\"id\":123}",
    "DoesNotWork": "{\"_a\":123,\"_b\":456}"
  }
]

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant That's a typo, I edited it. Are you using the BigQuery editor?

Comment: using BQ console - https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant  ` SELECT JSON_EXTRACT("{'category': 1, 'comments': [], 'free': False,'price': 55","$.price") AS Result `

Does this snippet return NULL? It does so for me in the console. If I change it to category, it works just fine, in that case the expected result (1) is shown in the console.

Comment: Change `False` to `false` or to `'False'` - depends on what this attribute represents - boolean or string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `true` and `false` instead of `True` or `False`

Comment: This was it! Big thanks. Was my mistake to not incldude it in the original data, but I guess it did help do solve the problem in the end. The original JSON file is coming straight from Firebase however, and in that data it's capitalized..

Comment: you can use regexp_replace to fix this on fly. post new question - you you will have issue in making this work :o)

Comment: I just realized using a simple REPLACE wouldn't work, as it would alter it across other potentially unwanted fields. I'm thinking maybe it's better to try and make sure it exports "correctly" from Firebase, but my dev says it's the raw format, so maybe it's something Google folks should correct

Comment: sure. just replace will not! that is why i mentioned regexp_replace as a hint for you :o) and obviously you can try something on firebase side  too

Comment: Yup, I think I will have to post another question later then. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use REPLACE, CAST, and EXTRACT to convert to lowercase true/false, extract the value, and cast as boolean.

```sql
CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(JSON_EXTRACT(REPLACE(REPLACE(yourColumn, ': True', ': true'), ': False', ': false'), "$.field2")) as bool) as yourAlias,
```

Assuming the form of `yourColumn` is like below and that you want `field2`'s boolean value.

```json
{'field1': True, 'field2': False}
```